# Java Code User Input to System.out

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.out

Small programming question here.

I'm trying to get line 43

```
System.out.print("Please Enter the Manufacturer of Your Doughnut:");
```

user input to paste directly into line 46

```
System.out.print("Please Enter the Manufacturer of Your Doughnut:");
```

but my compiler keeps giving me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at Torus.main(Torus.java:46)

For example, if the user wanted to input that their doughnuts were from McDonald's, line 46 would automatically spit out McDonald's.

[image: My Java Code]

Comment: Don't post as image. it should be as text.

Comment: I think you have a problem in line 44 (not sure which line sorry); when you use Scanner you have to use nextLine() (manufacter = input.nextLine()) for continue "reading", this is the reason of the throw exception in Scanner. Try to used it and print again.

Answer (score 1):

Well with input.nextDouble() the compiler is expecting a Double-Datatype. You need to get a string as manufacturer. I Think input.nextLine() should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `manufacturer` type from `double` to `String` and then use:

```
manufacturer = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the manufacturer variable to store a name, it should be of type [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) not `double`.
Change your declaration to

```
String manufacturer;
```

and to accept input use

```
manufacturer=input.nextLine(); //returns String
```